# Несколько - это сколько?

Tags: значение

Какое максимальное и минимальное количество подразумевает слово "`несколько`"?

Например:

- Если я сказал, что верну деньги через несколько дней, а вернул через 10 дней, выполнил ли я обещание?
- А если через месяц?
- А если сказал, что верну через несколько месяцев, а вернул через год?
- А если сказал, что знаю несколько языков, а знаю 3 языка - сказал ли я правду?

Comment: максимальное количество - 23 я считаю!

Comment: Этим вопросом многие интересовались, от Евбулида из Милета в IV в. до н. э. и до Слонёнка из советского мультфильма «38 попугаев»: [парадокс кучи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Парадокс_кучи). Варианты решения, на английском: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorites_paradox#Proposed_resolutions

Comment: И дело в том, что эта проблема не является сколько-нибудь специфичной для русского языка.

Comment: А я не про кучу, я про слово "несколько", это другое.  У кучи нет чёткого минимального размера, а у слова "несколько" может и быть.  5 - это точно несколько, 2 - нет.  Остаётся 3 и 4.  И с максимальным: год - это явно больше, чем несколько месяцев.

Comment: И у кучи, и у «несколько» есть чёткий минимальный размер: 2, ну или «больше одного». В любом случае речь идёт о _некоем_ отличном от одного числе. И это всё очень субъективно — вот вы точно уверены, что когда пишут: «в него выстрелили несколько раз», то это точно больше двух раз?

Comment: @YellowSky, субъективно, конечно, но 2 не годится. Два и пара имеют особое значение (и концептуально, и субъективно: именно поэтому многие языки имеют или имели отдельное двойственное число), и когда подразумевается 2 или около (но не "не знаю сколько, может, и 2"), "несколько" неприменимо. Нас, кажется, даже в школе этому учили специально.

Comment: "нечеткая" логика :)... ну, 20 это уже не очень "несколько"... хотя все еще зависит от контекста и субъекта, выдающего эти сентенции :> Чаще это всё же - до первого десятка :)

Comment: @Пилум - Если 20 в данном контексте значит «очень/исчезающе мало», то и 20 – это «несколько». Вот, например, в Украине самая маленькая монета сейчас 10 копеек, коробка спичек стоит 80 коп. Так что если у тебя в кармане всего, скажем, даже 40 копеек, то на вопрос, сколько у тебя с собой есть денег, вполне годным будет ответ: «Всего несколько копеек».

Comment: Yellow Sky нет. Всё это субъективно, и каждый решает сам - по "нечеткой логике" :>

Answer (score 4):

Если я сказал, что верну деньги через несколько дней, а вернул через 10 дней, выполнил ли я обещание? - возможно.

А если через месяц? - точно нет

А если сказал, что верну через несколько месяцев, а вернул через год? - 100% нет и вам больше не займут денег.

А если сказал, что знаю несколько языков, а знаю 3 языка - сказал ли я правду? - да

Comment: "не одолжат" лучше

Comment: если один из 3 языков - ваш родной, то вы не сказали правду

Answer (score 3):

Почти то же самое, что и "a few" по-английски.

Около пяти, но все числа между 3 и 8 - тоже.

Comment: "a few" rather than "few" - their meaning is different.

Comment: @Zeus правильно.

Answer (score 2):

Несколько - это столько, сколько человек не в состоянии сосчитать с первого взгляда, т.е. от трёх и более, правда тут важно и чего именно "несколько", у дробных показателей данное понятие может и раньше появится, но всё равно оно больше двух.

В общем, несколько - это минимум трое, но понятие - это относительное и потому индивидуальное. Современный человек, как правило, на глаз 3-4 предмета или существа различает, поэтому несколько для него начинается с пяти, а то и выше.

Заканчивается же несколько там, где человек переходит на другой порядок счёта (десяток, день, неделя).

Во всех ваших случаях обещание не исполнено, так как несколько дней - это в течение недели, а несколько недель - в течение месяца.

Answer (score 0):

I use **несколько** to mean 3,4,5. I am sure many will disagree with me but it's their problem.
If we take a week which comprises 7 days then it would be illogical to say "Я верну деньги через несколько дней" and pay it back after the week is over. **Несколько** однозначно меньше 7. 6 is also too high a number for несколько in my opinion. I confine it to 5 tops.

Answer (score 0):

Несколько usually means the precise amount of objects, as the @fraxinus said. The month has other 'value', so, I think this is not correct.

Of course, every person has its own "few", so it's impossible to find a strict amount of objects, amount of which we can say "несколько", so, I think, it depends on you

Answer (score -2):

Обычно, когда слово `несколько` собеседник хочет уточнить, он спрашивает `сколько примерно?`

На это можно ответить `3-4 штуки`, `2-3 недели`, `120-150 см`